# Exchange Slim for Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, rest, jwt

I have a restfull API built with Slim3 with JWT authentication.

I started to study Laravel and saw that it has many interesting features that make it easy to build an API.

So I'm evaluating the possibility of switching the framework from Slim to Laravel in the next API version.

So, I would like to check with the most experienced if there is any tool within Laravel that meets all the needs I have in the API.

Below I describe the operation.

In addition to the resources that will be consumed (PRODUCTS, FINANCIAL, STOCK, etc.) I have in the APIs the COMPANIES, USERS and PERMISSIONS tables.

When registering a new user, he will still not be allowed to access any resources besides his own registration.
Thus, the user requests a permission that creates a row in the PERMISSOES table with inactive status, as follows:

```
PERMISSION_ID COMPANY_ID USER_ID RESOURCE   GET POST PUT DELETE ACTIVE 
    1             1         1    FINANCIAL   1   1    0    0      0
```

This requested permission, when active, will give access to the FINANCIAL resource with COMPANY_ID 1, to the GET and POST methods to USER_ID 1.

The permission will be inactive until an ADMIN user from that company changes the PERMISSION status to active.

Thus, after the user logs in and the API returns a JWT that must be sent as a Header in all requests. Every time the user sends a request, for example to the FINANCIAL route, I make a query in the PERMISSOES table and check if the user is allowed to execute this resource with this method and for this company.
If allowed, access is granted and if not allowed, return a 401 error.

I would like to implement this logic in Laravel, is there any resource that facilitates the development or would I have to do everything by hand like I did in Slim?

If it is not clear what I need, let me know that I am changing the question.

Any help is most welcome.

It can be a tutorial, a video, a tip, seriously, anything.

I thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it by hand . However you can easily achieve those things in the laravel . However there are few libary/package that I can suggest you .

For jwt use this one
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

For laravel permission this is one of nice package
https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/

If you want to learn laravel then you can use laravel official documentation or this provides excellent video tutorials to begin with laravel

https://laracasts.com/

Comment: Hello, ashok. 
Thanks for the quick response and sorry for the delay in returning, I was focused on another project. About JWT I had already implemented an example in Laravel quite easily. As for permits, I will study about it, but it seems to me to be very useful for my need. Thanks again for the contribution.

Comment: Sure not a problem . If you like it feel free to upvote it